# How to run a docker image in windows 10?

Tags: command-line, terminal, git, docker, docker-for-windows

Can someone teach me how to run s docker image in windows 10?
Please don't tell me to read a tutorial, there is a reason why I ask.

I have already installed docker for windows.
All tutorials say, "Use docker quickstar terminal". Well that does not exist.
All there is is docker desktop.

I can run "docker ps" in any terminal, for example Git bash or the windows terminal (command prompt). However I want to run this

```
docker run -it -p 4567:4567 -v 'pwd':/work udacity/controls_kit:latest
```

if I do this on Git bash I got the following error:

```
the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'
```

and if I do this on the command prompt I got

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create 'pwd': "'pwd'" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What is the correct way to run a container image in windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

So close!

You're trying to evaluate the `pwd` command and use its result as part of the Docker call. It's done with *backtick* symbols (also called *grave accent*). On a US keyboard you can enter them with the button located over <kbd>Tab</kbd>, next to <kbd>1</kbd>. Currently you're (mis)using single quotes, which are used for quoting regular strings.

Ideally you should use `$(pwd)` rather than `` `pwd` ``. It does the same thing, but it's more predictable when nested and it's harder to get it confused with something else.

```
# should work:
winpty docker run -it -p 4567:4567 -v `pwd`:/work udacity/controls_kit:latest

# even better:
winpty docker run -it -p 4567:4567 -v $(pwd):/work udacity/controls_kit:latest
```

You need the `winpty` prefix due to running Docker on Windows with the default configuration. You can change this behavior during installation. On Windows 10 changing it is probably a good idea, since the improved command line doesn't have limitations that this feature aims to overcome.

Comment: should I run this on git bash?

Comment: Yes, `winpty` is specific for git bash and backticks/`$()` work in sh-compatible shells.